# rigging problem - why does the rig behave like it does?

Tags: rigging

I am a rigging noob and i tried to rig this simple setup here:

[image]

Just 3 bones, nothing special, last bone has IK.

The only "special" is, that the bones are limited to rotate around z.

The IK has target to the cube, which describes a simple circle.

Why is the rig behaving that wild!? In my opinion it could simple stay in on shape and just rotate? So obviously i made a total dumb mistake here...

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think it doesn't know how to bend at a certain point so it needs a pole target to help it, that's the function of the the pole target

Comment: Ok, thank you, i will try that…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your problem is that you haven't created a pole target so at some positions there is an ambiguity on how the bones are supposed to bend. Create a second empty, parent it to your target empty, and choose this second empty as the pole target of your IK bone, here is what it gives:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are my hero 